# List of Clients that connected to Oracle Historically

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Oracle 10G

Is it possible to get a list of all Client Programs that have connected to my Oracle Database Historically.

I can always get the current list of active sessions using V$SESSION but is there somewhere that historical connection information is recorded? I need this to know who all are using a particular database user for connecting to the database.

Comment: If you have a license for ASH, you could query `v$active_session_history` or if you need to go further back, `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY`

Answer (score 1):

You will find some information in the listener.log (executable, osuser)
As far as I know, audit trail is the only way to list connection history. If audit trail isn't enabled you are left with the listener.log and v$session.

Bjarte